# Apache Geode REST docs are missing

Tags: apache, geode

I'm interesting in using Apache Geode REST API, but i'm not able to find any doc on this.

I tried to follow the link on Github ([Geode REST](http://geode-docs.cfapps.io/docs/geode_rest/book_intro.html)), but doesn't seem to work.

Could you provide any doc or running example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST docs can be found at [http://geode.incubator.apache.org/docs/guide/rest_apps/book_intro.html](http://geode-docs.cfapps.io/docs/rest_apps/book_intro.html)

I will update the link on github.

Comment: fixed the broken link in [README](https://github.com/apache/incubator-geode/blob/develop/README.md)